# SQL Server 2014 Find Relationship among columns

Tags: sql, t-sql, group-by, relationship, sql-server-2014

I have hundreds of rows that may be related and it doesn't seem like a normal T-SQL GROUP BY will help me.  Here is the scenario:

Each row in a table contains an IP Address, an Email Address, and other contact information for a user.  A user can input many different rows, but I only care about the person's most complete contact information, I'm not interested in the number of times they contacted me.

Here is a sample table:

[image]

When I Group on Email, I get two remaining rows.  Depending on which IP I pick dynamically, I may not have a matching IP to then Group By IP.

It is the same problem the other way around.  Grouping by IP will render two remaining rows, then if I Group By Email, I have to worry about keeping the right IP Address to match on to get it down to one record.

The goal is to get one record (this is one person after all).  We can tell by either the email or the IP Address ( I do not want to use name).  I am fine with selecting any non-null value for any/all of the fields (min or max as the aggregate during the GROUP BY).

Can anyone point me in the right direction?  Thank you in advance.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a programming question.  It is a question about what business logic to use.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you got yourself to this predicament, but here's my advice. Use your email addresses as your primary key. Most people are less likely to have multiple email accounts that they try to use as a user ID. Note how many websites you are subscribed to using just your email. Also, it is possible for different people to use the same IP (example from the same household).

With that in mind, use this query:

```
SELECT EMAIL, MIN(FirstName) AS FirstName, Min(LastName) AS LastName, 
    Min(IPAddress) AS IPAddress
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY EMAIL
ORDER BY EMAIL
```

You will end up losing some data between the Roberts and Bobs, but if you really don't care about how Robert likes to be called Bob, but only on full moons and Tuesdays, then the above will work.

Also, if you are trying to make an address book out of this, IPAddress will probably not be much use to you. Most people don't have dedicated IPs, and might roam to different WiFi hotspots, so I would expect frequently changing IP addresses in a list of contacts made over time.

Comment: Hi @SandPiper, thanks for the speedy response.  I receive a large list of leads each day and I'm trying to roll the leads up to one contact per lead before inserting into a database.  I'm not necessarily storing the IP addresses, but it is a piece of information that can be used to indicate a relationship.  I do understand that people can have the same IP, and am willing to sacrifice complete accuracy, to get the records down to one.  I've even thought of concatenating the IP with the first letter of the first name and first letter of the last name.

Comment: The query you provided brings the records down to two records.  Is there a way to bring it down to one, dynamically?  Meaning, when I group on Email, I have to pick a scalar value for IP Address, and if it doesn't happen to be the IP Address that shares a value with the second record, I won't be able to then Group By IP.

Comment: There's always a way to do it, but the better question is should you? How positive are you that Bobby Doe and Robert Doe are really the same person? What if it is a father and son? Or two brothers? Take a minute to read over this: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem. It seems to me your best solution is to more effectively screen your data before it goes into your system. For the stuff that is already in there, find unique emails (I would gamble there are probably not TOO many duplicates), and you have your contact list.

Comment: I am asking this as more of a technical question and not necessarily a business question.  Independent of what the data actually is (this was just a sample table), I need to be able to identify relationships between rows on more than a column-to-column match.  Is this possible in SQL?  I have 5 rows and they are all related; some are related by one column, and some are related by another - but they are all related.  How do identify these 5 rows as 1 group?

Comment: Short answer: You don't. You can't definitively prove that each of those records is a duplicate and not a new distinct one. You can come up with a scheme that ties them all together, but it will never be 100% accurate. It is not an SQL problem, it is a logic problem.